# Don't know how to convert this list of latitudes and longitudes to work with Power BI visuals

Tags: powerbi, gis, powerbi-desktop

I have a table of cities in argentina with latitudes and longitudes but I can't figure out how to convert them so I can use them with PowerBI maps.

I don't have access to any GIS software nor do I know how to use it.

This is the file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1beGLzNtKQtnqIoaRpTomVQKjg6yJw48nmJ8XXyX2IYI/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

| localidad_id | localidad_nombre | localidad_centroide_lat | localidad_centroide_lon | provincia_id | provincia_nombre | departamento_id | departamento_nombre | municipio_id | municipio_nombre | localidad_censal_id | localidad_censal_nombre | localidad_categoria |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14098270000 | SUCO | -3343947297 | -6483166109 | 14 | Córdoba | 14098 | Río Cuarto | 142588 | Suco | 14098270 | Suco | Localidad simple |
| 46119010008 | SALICAS | -2840762581 | -6709615463 | 46 | La Rioja | 46119 | San Blas de Los Sauces | 460119 | San Blas de los Sauces | 46119010 | Salicas - San Blas | Entidad |

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GIS software often use integers to speed up calculations. In your case, you must divide the values in `localidad_centroide_lat` and `localidad_centroide_lon` by 100000000 to get the actual geo coordinates. After importing your files, add two [custom columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-add-custom-column), named for example `latitude` and `longitude`, as follows:

```
latitude = [localidad_centroide_lat] / 100000000
```

and

```
longitude = [localidad_centroide_lon] / 100000000
```

Make sure that their [data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/data-types) is `Decimal Number` and change it if you have to. Then, in the report designer, select each of them and make sure the [data category](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-data-categorization) of these fields is correctly set to `Latitude` and `Longitude`. Then you can use these new columns in your report to show data on a map:

[image]

Comment: Thank you it worked great.  NOw I'm having problems with a different set of data :(.  I posted a question