# How to convert this file of latitudes and longitudes to work with Power BI

Tags: powerbi, gis

I have a table of cities in argentina with latitudes and longitudes but I can't figure out how to convert them so I can use them with PowerBI maps.

I don't have access to any GIS software nor do I know how to use it.

This is the file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qdmFGGIeT7yeBYvCc2HA6CfccyeCbJAY/view?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post an example data row instead of linking to an external file

Comment: What is different in this case, comparing to that one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73778805/dont-know-how-to-convert-this-list-of-latitudes-and-longitudes-to-work-with-pow

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Don't know how to convert this list of latitudes and longitudes to work with Power BI visuals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73778805/dont-know-how-to-convert-this-list-of-latitudes-and-longitudes-to-work-with-pow)

Comment: This is in a different format.  Thanks in advance

Comment: These aren't just latitudes and longitudes, but multipolygons with shapes. What do you want to do with them - to extract one point and show it on a map, or to visualize the whole multipolygon? If you try to use Power BI as a complete GIS system, probably it isn't the right tool for you. Otherwise, either try to get the data in another, more convenient format, or try to convert it yourself (inside or outside Power BI).

Comment: Helllo Andrey.  I don't have access to any GIS software.  I just need the coordinates for the cities.  Is there a way to get them from the polygons?

Comment: First,there is no coordinates of the cities there.There are (multi)polygons, which are maybe the shapes of these cities,or something else.Eventually you can extract one point from these shapes and use this as the location, but it isn't a logical center of that city.Try to use [Text.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-replace) to remove the shape type and brackets,then to [split by comma](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/split-columns-delimiter) to get the first point,but I do not understand these numbers (second one looks like longitude, but 1st isn't lat)

Comment: Thanks @AndreyNikolov. Does anyone know what these numbers mean?  Thanks

Comment: What I've found is a reference to the coordinates being in system EPSG 32721... Any clue?

Comment: I also found this code to transform from ESPG 32721 to latitude and longitude but I don't know Python...

from pyproj import Proj, transform

inProj = Proj(init='epsg:3857')
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')
x1,y1 = -11705274.6374,4826473.6922
x2,y2 = transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1)
print x2,y2